# rpart.plot remove scientific notation

Tags: r, rpart

```
> fit <- rpart(price ~ carat + cut + clarity, diamonds_train, method = "anova")

> rpart.plot(fit, type = 4, extra = 101)
```

I tried `options(scipen=10)` but it didn't work. How can I remove the scientific notation?

[image]

Comment: Quoting from the documentation of rpart.plot on digits parameter: 
The number of significant digits in displayed numbers. Default 2. If 0, use getOption("digits").
Details: Numbers from 0.001 to 9999 are printed without an exponent (and the number of digits is actually only a suggestion, see format for details). Numbers out that range are printed with an “engineering” exponent (a multiple of 3).

Answer (score 5):

Use a negative value for the `digits` argument.  The `rpart.plot` help page says that if `digits` is negative, `rpart.plot` uses the standard R `format` function (with the absolute value of `digits`):

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
library(rpart.plot)
fit <- rpart(price ~ carat + cut + clarity, diamonds, method = "anova")
rpart.plot(fit, type = 4, extra = 101, digits=-3)
```

This requires `rpart.plot` version 2.1.2 or higher.  You may have play with the value `digits=-3` to get the exact display you want.